# OSError tsv not found

Tags: python-3.x, sentiment-analysis

I am taking this error:
OSError: \C:\Users\u165127\Desktop\Restaurant_Reviews.tsv not found.

I am so confused!

```
#import the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import the dataset
import scipy as sp
data = sp.genfromtxt(r'\C:\Users\u165127\Desktop\Restaurant_Reviews.tsv',delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: also tried: dataset = pd.read_csv('../input/Restaurant_Reviews.tsv', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 3)

Answer (score 0):

It means the file location given by `r'\C:\Users\u165127\Desktop\Restaurant_Reviews.tsv'` doesn't exist.

You could try: `'C:\Users\u165127\Desktop\Restaurant_Reviews.tsv'`

Or if the script runs from `C:\Users\u165127\Desktop` simply try `"./Restaurant_Reviews.tsv"`

Comment: dataset = pd.read_csv('./Restaurant_Reviews.tsv', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 3)                                                                                                                         Again I take the error: FileNotFoundError: File b'./Restaurant_Reviews.tsv' does not exist

Comment: Then the file is not in the same directory as your script is running from

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: Put the file in the same directory, or run the script from the directory where the file is, or use the absolute path of the file

Comment: I use the absolute path and I am getting this: OSError: Initializing from file failed

Answer (score 0):

```
def load_csv(Restaurant_Reviews):
    file = open(Restaurant_Review, 'r')
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return text
```

## This is running but I do not understand the difference